PDF produced correctly despite error
I am getting an error when compiling my pdf: "Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.". Nevertheless, the PDF is produced correctly (it is not an old PDF, I checked). How is this possible? Shouldn't an error stop the PDF from compiling correctly?
Details: I am using the optidef package, and the error occurs when I try to use a "maxi!" environment (when using a "maxi" environment, no error).

by default an error pauses on the commandline and you can choose to scroll past, some editors run tex in scrollmode so that it always tries to get the end so they can parse the log and allow you to step through errors. any pdf made after an error isn't usable for anything other than debugging, tex only recovers enough to continue processing it doesn't attempt to make sensible output

Welcome to TeX.SX! I've no problem using maxi! environment. So if you want to know the root of the error and how to correct it, please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

Thank you to everyone who responded. I now understand how LaTeX created a pdf despite the error.  As for the error itself with maxi!, I am having trouble to recreate it with a MWE. I suspect that the problem may be with the conference template I am using. I will look into that and in case that is not the problem, I will post a MWE.

A typical cause of the error shown is
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \textbf[aaa} bbb
\end{center}


\end{document}

If you run this on the commandline TeX will stop with:
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.6   \textbf[aaa}
                   bbb
?

At the command prompt you can do various responses: in particular h explains how TeX recovers in this case:
? h
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

? 

So the document will be processed as if it were
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \textbf[aaa bbb
\end{center}


\end{document}

producing

with a bold [ and non bold aaa  which is almost certainly not what was intended (the correct fix would be to replace the [ with {)  but allows TeX to process the document.
Many TeX editors and IDE always run TeX in "scrollmode" so it does not stop at an error and always tries to reach the end, This allows then to display some output and allows them to parse the log and provide an interface that lists all errors found.
So after an error The PDF should never be trusted for actual use but (like the bold [ here) can help, in combination with the error messages in the log, to trace the cause of the error.
